# How to use static libraries in MSVS2015 for x64?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

This code

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    return 0;
}
```

does not compiling in MSVS2015Enterprise for Debug or Release x64:

```
1>------ START COMPILING: PROJECT: SFML_Test, CONFIGURATION: Release x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: FILE "sfml-graphics.lib" NOT FOUND
========== BUILD: SUCCESSFULLY: 0, WITH ERRORS: 1, UNCHANGED: 0, SKIPPED: 0 ==========
```

**Release x64, LINK : fatal error LNK1181**

But directory `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\` has `sfml-graphics.lib`.

How can I fix it?

This is true for all source-files with string `#pragma comment(lib, "MyLib.lib")`!

Comment: You may get better results here with translating the error messages to english.

Comment: Important information: Release x64, LINK : fatal error LNK1181, file "sfml-graphics.lib" not found.

Comment: It is a standart output in visual studio

Comment: Never, never, never copy libraries into VS install directories.  Many problems with it, but also causes this kind of breakage, the linker looks in vc\lib\amd64 for 64-bit projects.

Answer (score 0):

This [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6b12xkc.aspx) occurs because linker is not able to find `sfml-graphics.lib` library. I guess you specify **Additional Library Directories** in Linker options without the quotation marks around the path. Proper value should be:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib"
```

Comment: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib" is STANDART Library Directory. I hadn't this problem before.

Comment: @KonstantinDedov Please check your project options carefully. There is no `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib` included by default.

Comment: I solve this problem: the default is ".../VC/lib/amd64/"